# what approach does Apple IOS Maps use to show annotation details? (image attached)

Tags: ios, mapkit, uistoryboard, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

What approach does apple use in it's IOS Maps apps for show the annotation details?

For example to reproduce this in your own app would it be via creation of a View Controller in Storyboard and then use of the "popover" method, however in this case I would normally see on iPhone it taking up the whole screen, so it seems it's a different approach or you have to do some special customisation above & beyond the base "popover" approach?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK there's no such standard UI component in iOS, so they probably created it themselves with just a (possibly custom) UIView added to their main view, along with gesture recognisers to handle the resizing.

Comment: oh...if recreating would we still use a UIViewController present, and in this case and thoughts on the presentation approach (e.g. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle)?